# React MUI using `responsiveFontSizes` with `experimental_extendTheme` and `Experimental_CssVarsProvider`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to use React MUI's [`responsiveFontSizes`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes) with a theme created using [`extendTheme`](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/customization/) rather than the traditional `createTheme`, but when doing so I get a typing error:

```
import { experimental_extendTheme as extendTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import responsiveFontSizes from '@mui/material/styles/responsiveFontSizes';

const theme = responsiveFontSizes(extendTheme());
```

```
Type of property 'breakpoints' circularly references itself in mapped type 'Omit<CssVarsTheme, "palette">'.
```

[Here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-i3uagq?file=src%2FApp.tsx) showing the typing error when using `responsiveFontSizes` with the experimental `extendTheme`.

It seems to work aside from the typing error. Is this an issue with MUI's typing or are they incompatible?